# Path Integral equals zero on non conservative field

Tags: calculus, integration, greens-theorem

I was doing some excercises and I was asked to compute the line integral along certain path. I used greens formula to calculate the work. When computing the integral I had to divide the domain in two sections and one of those domains equals zero. Is this possible?

Here is what I have done so far (its question 1.2)

[image: Question[![][1]]][Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fxG1.jpg):

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It seems to me that $C_1$ is a semi-circle in the upper half plane, and $C_2$ is a parabolic arc running from $(0,-1)$ to $(1,0)$.  Your picture doesn't look like this, and $C_1\cup C_2$ is not a closed curve.   Perhaps the domain for $C_1$ is supposed to be $t\in[0,3\pi/2]$

Comment: There is supposed to be a line from (0,0) to (0,-1), and thus closing the curve. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The semi circle is the upper half of the unit circle.  It doesn't pass through $(0,0).$  It passes through the points $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0).$  Also, there is nothing in the question about a line segment connecting $C_1$ and $C_2,$ and you aren't justified in drawing one.  But the question makes no sense as written, so far as I can see.  $C_1\cup C_2$ in *not* a closed curve, despite what the question says, and it's hard to know what to make of parts 2 and 3.  Ask your teacher about it.  If there's no way to do that, assume that $t$ is supposed to run from $0$ to $3\pi/2$ for $C_1.$

Comment: @saulspatz is right. Unless your second parameter has values $t\in [-1,1]$ (or your first parameter has values $t \in [0, \frac{3\pi}{2} $] this is not a closed curve. Hence, Green's Theorem cannot be applied. I would assume this is most likely a typo though.

Comment: @Hotdog A different possible typo!  I didn't think of that one.

Answer (score 2):

For a conservative field $\vec{F}$ the curve integral $\oint_\gamma \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = 0$ for *every* closed path $\gamma$.

If a field is not conservative, the integral can still be zero for a lot of closed curves, but not for every curve.